# Hashes in the "Beginning Ruby: From Novice to Expert" Book

Tags: ruby

I'm reading this book and hashes are done like this:

```
{:hash1 => :reference}
```

why does the author put a colon before reference and what does it do? Is it the same as this?

```
{:hash1 => reference}
```

or is there a purpose to the colon before reference?

Comment: `:reference` is literal for Ruby [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html). Keep reading and you're likely to learn what you want.

Comment: also, it'll produce same results if reference = :reference ;)

Answer (score 1):

In following example `:reference` is a value or symbol more precisely. `:reference` and `reference` both are not same because `reference` represents a variable/method.

```
{:hash1 => :reference}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Both are completely different

```
:reference
```

is literal for Ruby Symbol

and

```
reference
```

is ruby variable or method..etc